Suggestion to change the FAQ
In our FAQ it is clearly says that this site is not about politics. I just created a suggestion to open a site just for that. 
Will it be rude for me to ask you to mention this site in the FAQ, as alternative to anyone who is seeking to discuss about Bitcoin politics?
Also I hope I am not valuating any rules by asking that.

Um, I don't want to discourage your effort, but the example questions you are listing would also fit here well enough, except that they are primarily opinion based and thus prone to incite discussion. Unfortunately, that is not something that the Stackexchange format facilitates. I.e. without even talking about amendments to the FAQ, which I honestly don't even know the procedure for, I don't really see how your proposal is supposed to work out on SE.

I don't agree with you. "How the New-Year-2014 is going to effect Bitcoin?", is a question about politics and does not feet this site, without speaking about it's prone to incite discussion...
